# Using Mono or Bouncy Castle c# for TLS implementation

Tags: c#, mono, cryptography, bouncycastle, ssl

Can Mono be used as a regular open source cryptographic library? For example, using Mono.security.tls only.

I'm asking because I'm adding tls to a program previously written by another person who didn't use Mono from the start.

Or it is better to use Bouncy Castle?

Comment: [This page](http://www.mono-project.com/Cryptography) is a little out of date but might be helpful for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the code from `Mono.Security.dll` can be used outside of Mono, e.g. on Microsoft .NET. In fact it was the main goal of this assembly.

A lot of the code that it contains already exists (or is reused) to build the Mono's base class library (e.g. `X509Certificate` support in mscorlib.dll, SSL/TLS support in System.dll) or the .NET related tools shipped with Mono (e.g. `makecert`, `signcode`, `sn` ...).

So it would have been a shame not exposing it publicly into a assembly. Of course you can still use the sources files you require and add them into your applications (it's MIT.X11 licensed).

Comment: Since I am implementing TLS for an application. Would it be better to use Bouncy Castle as it's a library dedicated to crypto? While Mono it's a large project, which consists of many other sections.

Comment: That should not matter IMO. OTOH you should use what the .NET BCL already provides you, e.g. `SslStream` (since 2.0 offers both client and server side support), to avoid adding any non-required dependency to your application. Of course if you need something specific it does not offer then this will limit your choices...

Comment: Using .Net BCL, I'm worried about whether it is robust as the code is not open to public for testing of security issues, which is one for the plus points for open-source libraries. Is my concern valid? I'm very new to this.

Comment: That's a valid concern **but** this works **only** if you are willing to track every bug and new releases of all your dependencies (against security issues). Even then there could be other security issues on the MS .NET JIT/BCL (assuming you're not using/tracking Mono everywhere) that worse than any issue about TLS. If you use MS.NET then you already gave up *parts* of **will review myself** strategy and still depend on your users to get notified when a .NET update is available.